# Chatter in Apex using Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, chatter-api

I'm fairly new to Lightning Design System.So need some guidance here.
I'm trying to build Chatter in Apex using Lightning components. Using rest Api, I am getting the Chatter Feed of a group in my org and putting in a vf component. So far unable to do so as getting the long list of error 
"An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1737214086-58136 (-1487509830)
org.auraframework.throwable.AuraUnhandledException: apex://text: 404 Not Found (Application Error)". I don't understand what is Unhandled here. Please review my code. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
  app:
=======
     <apex:page controller="ChatterFeedController">
     <apex:includeLightning />
     <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
     <apex:stylesheet value="/resource/SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-
     lightning-design-system-vf.css"/>
    <div id="lightning" />
  <script>
 var groupId = "0F98E0000004UhA";

          $Lightning.use("c:THORannouncementApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:THORAnnouncementlghtcomp",
          {groupattid : groupId},               
         "lightning",
         function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
         });        
         }
        );   </script>
```

```
    Component:
===============
<aura:component controller ="ChatterFeedController">
<aura:attribute name = "groupattid" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name = "groupatt" type="String[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.userFeedItem}" value="{!this}"/> 

<div class ="slds">
<!--Page Header-->
 <div class="slds-page-header">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <h1 class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate"
            title="THOR Announcement">THOR Announcement</h1>
    </div>
 </div>
    <section class="slds-card__body">
    <div id = "List" class="row">           

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.groupatt}" var="att">
            <span class="slds-truncate">{!att.elements.body.messageSegments.text}</span>
        </aura:iteration> 
     </div> 
     </section>
```

```
          Controller.js
          =============
({ 
userFeedItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var userFeed = componenet.get("c.getFeedData");
    userFeed.setParams({groupattid : component.get("v.groupattid")});
    userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
           console.log("USERS_BODY: " + JSON.stringify(userFeed));
        componenet.set("v.groupatt",response.getReturnValue());
        } else {
            console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
        }    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userFeed);
}
})

    chatterfeedcontroller.cls   
    ==========================
     @AuraEnabled
     global static ConnectApi.FeedElementPage getFeedData(String groupId) {
    ConnectApi.FeedElementPage feedElementPage = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(communityId,ConnectApi.FeedType.Record,groupId);

          System.debug(JSON.serializePretty('feedElementPage--
          >'+feedElementPage+'feedElementPage-->'));

       return feedElementPage;
      }
```

Comment: Try serializing your returntype to string in getFeedData() method.